# If a row does not exist, check a second column on a join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to join a table on a column

```
Select * From tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b
ON a.key = b.foreignkey
...
```

If that row cannot be found I want to join it to another column in table B.  Is there an efficient way to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` to join on the first non-`NULL` column.

```
Select * From tableA a
LEFT JOIN tableB b
ON a.key = COALESCE(b.foreignkey, b.another_column, b.another_column2)
```

It will try to join with `b.foreignkey` first. if that is `NULL` then `b.foreignkey` and so on.

Please find the example **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d052e8c3fbb8798b8b1f29c5b62c24e5)**.

Answer (score 1):

Add another `LEFT JOIN`:

```
Select *
From tableA a left join
     tableB b
     on a.key = b.foreignkey left join
     tableC c
     on a.key = c.foreignkey and b.foreignkey is null;
```